# Apache SSL on 64-bit Windows (not a valid Win32 application)

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, ssl, 32bit-64bit

I have created a portable (relative paths) Apache installation. It works perfectly on my 32-bit system, but when I try to run it on a 64-bit system, it gives the following error:

```
>httpd -t
httpd: Syntax error on line … of …/httpd.conf: Cannot load …/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

If I comment out the line that includes `SSL.conf`, then the server runs on the 64-bit system, but of course without SSL support.

I have tried searching for this but cannot find anything helpful. Does anybody know how to get Apache to use SSL on a 64-bit system (preferably in a way that is compatible with a 32-bit system)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), I observed the file and registry entry accesses that Apache makes when loading.

I noticed that `httpd` loads the file `libeay32.dll` at the end of the trace (just before it errors out). I tried putting a copy of `libeay32.dll` from a [64-bit Apache package](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/) I got from ApacheLounge in Apache’s `bin` directory, but it still gave the same error. (I suppose that should not be a surprise, because the file it was previously loading was a already a 64-bit copy from some folder—which is in the `PATH`—where one of the laptop’s 64-bit drivers are installed.)

I then put a **32-bit** copy of `libeay32.dll` (*and* `ssleay32.dll`) that I got from the standard package, et voilà! Apache runs with SSL support on a 64-bit system! Moreover, because the copy of `libeay32.dll` is 32-bits, it still runs on the 32-bit system **without modification** (i.e., no detecting the system and replacing files or even conf-file hacks)!

(I’m glad I put the error message in the title of the question because it will hopefully help direct others with this problem—which I struggled with for several months—to this page where they can finally find the solution. ☺)

Comment: I had a similar problem and ended up using the `libeay32.dll (and ssleay32.dll` from a 32-bit version of PHP 5.5 (in my case I had to replace the ones that came with PHP v5.3 with the ones included in v5.5)

Comment: Helpful, I also downloaded 32 bits version and it is working for me.

Comment: same issue with mod_ssl and php 5.6 on wamp solve it by copy files libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from php 7.0.4 package.

Comment: I copied `libesy` and `ssleay` from `php7` folder to apache/bin, and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have 64bit mod_jk.so which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/) by version. I hope it is helpful.